# concatenate date periods

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table as follows which contains periods of contracts:

| id | year | startdate | enddate | drop_out | covered_days |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2015 | 2015-03-01 | 2020-12-31 | *null* | *null* |
| 1 | 2016 | 2015-03-01 | 2020-12-31 | *null* | *null* |
| 1 | 2017 | 2015-03-01 | 2020-12-31 | *null* | *null* |
| 1 | 2018 | 2015-03-01 | 2020-12-31 | *null* | *null* |
| 1 | 2019 | 2015-03-01 | 2020-12-31 | *null* | *null* |
| 1 | 2020 | 2015-03-01 | 2020-12-31 | *null* | *null* |
| 1 | 2021 | 2021-01-01 | 2021-04-20 | 2021-04-20 | 2242 |
| 3 | 2014 | 2014-03-01 | 2019-08-09 | *null* | *null* |
| 3 | 2015 | 2014-03-01 | 2019-08-09 | *null* | *null* |
| 3 | 2016 | 2014-03-01 | 2019-08-09 | *null* | *null* |
| 3 | 2017 | 2014-03-01 | 2019-08-09 | *null* | *null* |
| 3 | 2018 | 2014-03-01 | 2019-08-09 | *null* | *null* |
| 3 | 2019 | 2014-03-01 | 2019-08-09 | 2019-08-09 | 1987 |
| 3 | 2019 | 2019-08-12 | 2020-01-31 | *null* | *null* |
| 3 | 2020 | 2019-08-12 | 2020-01-31 | 2020-01-31 | 172 |
| 5 | 2015 | 2015-03-01 | 2015-03-31 | *null* | *null* |
| 5 | 2015 | 2015-04-01 | 2015-04-09 | 2015-04-09 | 39 |
| 5 | 2015 | 2015-04-11 | 2015-04-16 | 2015-04-16 | 5 |
| 5 | 2015 | 2015-04-18 | 2015-04-23 | 2015-04-23 | 5 |
| 5 | 2016 | 2016-06-01 | 2016-07-30 | *null* | *null* |
| 5 | 2016 | 2016-07-31 | 2017-02-03 | *null* | *null* |
| 5 | 2017 | 2016-07-31 | 2017-02-03 | *null* | *null* |
| 5 | 2017 | 2017-02-04 | 2017-09-13 | 2017-09-13 | 469 |
| 5 | 2017 | 2017-09-15 | 2017-09-17 | 2017-09-17 | 2 |
| 5 | 2017 | 2017-09-19 | 2019-04-08 | *null* | *null* |
| 5 | 2018 | 2017-09-19 | 2019-04-08 | *null* | *null* |
| 5 | 2019 | 2017-09-19 | 2019-04-08 | 2019-04-08 | 566 |
| 5 | 2019 | 2019-04-10 | 2019-04-26 | 2019-04-26 | 16 |
| 5 | 2019 | 2019-04-28 | 2020-12-31 | *null* | *null* |
| 5 | 2020 | 2019-04-28 | 2020-12-31 | 2020-12-31 | 613 |

If you take a look at `ID` 1 the first period starts on 2015-03-01 up to 2020-12-31 but a second period follows without a gap starting on 2021-01-01 up to 2021-04-20. I need to concatenate these periods.

`ID` 3 and 5 have gaps in between their periods. Thus, I need to list every period separately.

I would like to create a table that takes into account the respective periods like that:

| id | year | startdate | enddate | drop_out | covered_days |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2015 | 2015-03-01 | 2021-04-20 | 2021-04-20 | 2242 |
| 1 | 2016 | 2015-03-01 | 2021-04-20 | 2021-04-20 | 2242 |
| 1 | 2017 | 2015-03-01 | 2021-04-20 | 2021-04-20 | 2242 |
| 1 | 2018 | 2015-03-01 | 2021-04-20 | 2021-04-20 | 2242 |
| 1 | 2019 | 2015-03-01 | 2021-04-20 | 2021-04-20 | 2242 |
| 1 | 2020 | 2015-03-01 | 2021-04-20 | 2021-04-20 | 2242 |
| 3 | 2014 | 2014-03-01 | 2019-08-09 | 2019-08-09 | 1987 |
| 3 | 2015 | 2014-03-01 | 2019-08-09 | 2019-08-09 | 1987 |
| 3 | 2016 | 2014-03-01 | 2019-08-09 | 2019-08-09 | 1987 |
| 3 | 2017 | 2014-03-01 | 2019-08-09 | 2019-08-09 | 1987 |
| 3 | 2018 | 2014-03-01 | 2019-08-09 | 2019-08-09 | 1987 |
| 3 | 2019 | 2014-03-01 | 2019-08-09 | 2019-08-09 | 1987 |
| 3 | 2019 | 2019-08-12 | 2020-01-31 | 2020-01-31 | 172 |
| 3 | 2020 | 2019-08-12 | 2020-01-31 | 2020-01-31 | 172 |

I have tried the following but it does only work for `ID` 1 which has no gap in between the periods.

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/XgFLeYUr)

```
WITH CombinedPeriods AS (
  SELECT
    id,
    startdate AS combined_startdate,
    enddate AS combined_enddate,
    covered_days AS combined_coverage_days
  FROM YourTableName 
  UNION 
  SELECT
    id,
    CASE WHEN LAG(enddate) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY startdate) >= startdate THEN LAG(enddate) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY startdate) ELSE startdate END AS combined_startdate,
    enddate AS combined_enddate,
    covered_days AS combined_coverage_days
  FROM YourTableName
)
SELECT
  id,
  MIN(combined_startdate) AS combined_startdate,
  MAX(combined_enddate) AS combined_enddate,
  SUM(combined_coverage_days) AS combined_coverage_days
FROM CombinedPeriods
GROUP BY id;
```

Comment: Haven't you asked this before? Looks familiar

Comment: @siggemannen I asked how to retrieve the data table which is the base for this question.

Comment: the problem is that your data is not normalized. you should just store start -> end, and from that build your final table. Now you gotta work twice as hard

Comment: So you mean just selecting the startdates and enddates per `ID` `INTO` another table and then keep building the table?

Comment: yeah, something like that. I mean, the "year" part of your table is very weird, it's more like a snapshot, and it should be a view generated from "real" contract table. That's my opinion at least

Comment: I understand. but it will be used as a linkage to other tables which are divided into years.

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH RecursivePeriods AS (
  SELECT
    id,
    year,
    startdate,
    enddate,
    drop_out,
    covered_days,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY startdate) AS rn
  FROM YourTableName
),
CombinedPeriods AS (
  SELECT
    rp1.id,
    rp1.year,
    rp1.startdate AS combined_startdate,
    rp1.enddate AS combined_enddate,
    rp1.drop_out AS combined_drop_out,
    rp1.covered_days AS combined_coverage_days,
    rp1.rn
  FROM RecursivePeriods rp1
  LEFT JOIN RecursivePeriods rp2 ON rp1.id = rp2.id AND rp1.rn = rp2.rn - 1
  WHERE rp2.id IS NULL
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    cp.id,
    rp.year,
    cp.combined_startdate,
    CASE WHEN rp.startdate > cp.combined_enddate THEN rp.enddate ELSE cp.combined_enddate END,
    CASE WHEN rp.startdate > cp.combined_enddate THEN rp.drop_out ELSE cp.combined_drop_out END,
    CASE WHEN rp.startdate > cp.combined_enddate THEN rp.covered_days ELSE cp.combined_coverage_days END,
    rp.rn
  FROM CombinedPeriods cp
  JOIN RecursivePeriods rp ON cp.id = rp.id AND cp.rn = rp.rn - 1
)
SELECT
  id,
  year,
  combined_startdate,
  MAX(combined_enddate) AS combined_enddate,
  MAX(combined_drop_out) AS combined_drop_out,
  SUM(combined_coverage_days) AS combined_coverage_days
FROM CombinedPeriods
GROUP BY id, year, combined_startdate
ORDER BY id, year;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your approach. It does not add the individual periods with gaps for `ID` 3 and 5.